# Having error, Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to update value in the table's column in sql server which is of type decimal(2,2) and I have used following query to update that

```
update Bedding
  set Bedroom = 1.0
  where BeddingId = 5
```

But I am having following error :Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type   numeric.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You confirmed both Bedroom and BeddingId are numeric?

Comment: Yes, BeddingId is int and Bedroom is decimal(2,2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am column defined as decimal(n,m) holds n decimal digits, m of which are the fraction part. So decimal(2,2) is 2 digits long, both of which are the fraction part. This will only be able to take values in the range -0.99 to 0.99.

Comment: ok, so i need to change the datatype of Bedroom from decimal(2,2) to decimal(3,2) if i want to enter this type of value. Thanks, for explanation